# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT --builds successful but app crashes in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got this error after putting in this section of code to an app I'm making

```
PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Whenever I hit run, it says "Build Successful" but the app the crashes in the simulator. Can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: If it crashes, there is an error message in console? Could you give it?

Comment: FYI - a successful build does not mean your app doesn't have bugs that can lead to a crash at runtime.

Comment: You need to point out the exact line of code causing the crash and you need to update your question with the complete error message.

Comment: I can't find any reference to `viewControllerAtIndex:` in the developer docs. Is this a custom method you've written? If so, you need to provide it, because, if I had to guess, your app is crashing because you're trying to access an array index that doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing may be wrong here is that `[self viewControllerAtIndex:0];` returns NULL. You cannot create NSArray with NULL element.